# Reusable active/inactive radio button is not passing a value

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with a series of forms for a website, each one has a binary active/inactive state attached to the data field. I wanted to make a single radio button setup I could put into every form but when I run it I see that the value being output doesn't match either of the values I set to the options.

```
        return (
            <div className="radio-btn-container" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <RadioButton 
                    changed={ this.radioChangeHandler } 
                    id="rdoBtnActive" 
                    isSelected={ this.state.Status === "1" } 
                    label="Active" 
                    value="1"
                />
                <RadioButton 
                    changed={ this.radioChangeHandler } 
                    id="rdoBtnActive" 
                    isSelected={ this.state.Status === "0" } 
                    label="Inactive" 
                    value="0" 
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Is my issue somewhere in the creation of this radio? Or is there something particular I need to call or declare on the pages that it's used?

Comment: Is your state value a string? `this.state.Status === "0"` will only return true if it is a string of "0". You might be meaning to use `this.state.Status === 0` or even just `this.state.Status == 0`

Comment: No, I'm trying to get it for a binary 1-0 thing like how mysql seems to take boolean statements. I'll adjust that and see how it goes.

Comment: ```sqlMessage: 'Incorrect integer value: \'\' for column \'Active\' at row 1',
```

Comment: Remember `==` will attempt "type coercion" before it compares values so that `1 == '1'` is true, but `===` will not attempt to convert types so that `1 === '1'` is false

Comment: That error doesn't seem related to the code you provided.

Comment: ```
import RadioBtnActive from '../components/RadioBtnActive'
...
</div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlfor="Active">Active status</label>    
                        <RadioBtnActive/>
                        
                        </div>```

I think the problem is that I'm not getting a value out of the radio buttons on the page it's being called from.